# Run a powershell script to access blob storage using a proxy

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to access and download the blob content from Azure using powershell.
Information:

- OS - Windows 2012 R2
- Powershell version - 5.1
- Az modules installed - Az.Account and Az.storage

I'm running the script bellow with my user directly on the server and run successfully.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name ProxyServer -Value "proxy:port"
 Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -name ProxyEnable -Value 1
    
 $storageAccountName = "myAccount"
 $token = "mytoken"
 $container = "mycontainer"
 $blob = 'myblob'
    
 $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -SasToken $token
    
 $blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container -Context $Context -Blob $blob
```

But when I put this code on a SQL Agent Job (runs with another login) with the command: powershell.exe -File myfile.ps1, I've got the error:

> Get-AzStorageBlob : An error occurred while sending the request. At
> line:1 char:9
>
> - $blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "mycontainer" -Context ...
> - 
> - CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzStorageBlob], StorageException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageBlob
>   Command

This looks a timeout error the same way if I remove the proxy configuration an run the script with my login. How can I set this proxy for the SQL Agent login?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my suggestion works.

I think that you should look for in how to set a proxy configuration within the SQL agent job.

You are executing the powershell script in your local machine, that works well.

In SQL agent job when you run powershell.exe , it is SQL agent job who takes care of the network configuration and proxies.

I suggest you to find out how to add the proxyserver option in the powershell.exe command line in the agent, not in the script. When executing the script from the agent,the 2 first lines regarding to the proxy should be commented (or deleted).

The other brutal solution is to change the proxy server in your system, but all the system will be envolved to that proxy, not a good practice.